# Numpy tobytes method is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, ros2

I'm trying to publish a PointCloud2 message to a ROS2 network. But the conversion from the numpy array which holds my points to the byte data I insert into the message takes almost 2 seconds for every single frame.

Here is my code, the culprit is the points.tobytes() method. It takes around 2 seconds for an array of shape (1024, 768, 6) which seems a bit much.

```
    def publish_points(self, points):
        msg = PointCloud2()
        msg.header.frame_id = 'lidar_link'
        msg.width = WIDTH
        msg.height = HEIGHT
        ros_dtype = PointField.FLOAT32
        dtype = np.float32
        itemsize = np.dtype(dtype).itemsize
        msg.fields = [PointField(
            name=n, offset=i * itemsize, datatype=ros_dtype, count=1)
            for i, n in enumerate('xyzrgb')]
        msg.data = points.tobytes()
        msg.is_dense = False
        msg.is_bigendian = False
        msg.point_step = 6 * itemsize
        msg.row_step = 6 * itemsize * WIDTH
        msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()

        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
```

Are there any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: It takes 2 milliseconds for me... For `ar = np.random.rand(1024, 768, 6).astype(np.float32)`

Comment: Please provide a minimal *reproducible* example. There is no reason this code should be slow.

Comment: You're right, it was actually the assignment to the msg.data that took that long. I worked around that by assigning it to the private member msg._data which seems to circumvent some hidden bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

I was mistaken when thinking it was the .tobytes() call that was that slow.
It actually was the assignment to the data attribute of the PointCloud2 message. I managed to get around it by assigning to the private attribute _data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).